# Removing characters from string Python

Tags: python, string

I'm trying to write a function that gets rid of the vowels in a given string, but it seems to not behave the way it should do...

```
def anti_vowel(text):
    for c in text:
        if c in "aeiouAEIOU":
            no_vowel = text.replace(c, '')
    return no_vowel
print(anti_vowel('Hello World')
```

so instead of printing

```
Hll Wrld
```

It prints

```
Hell Wrld
```

Thanks (in advance) for helping

Comment: Where is `no_vowel` defined?

Answer (score 9):

The problem is that `no_vowel` only has the value of the last time that `text.replace(c, '')` was executed. Another issue is that `no_vowel` only gets a value when there is actually a vowel to remove; the code would fail on `anti_vowel('vwllss')`. Furthermore, you don't have to check whether a character is contained in the text before calling `str.replace()`.

This should work:

```
def anti_vowel(text):
    for vowel in "aeiouAEIOU":
        text = text.replace(vowel, '')
    return text
print(anti_vowel('Hello World'))
```

As others indicated, another approach would be to write code in a different way:

```
def anti_vowel(text):
    ''.join(c for c in text if c not in 'aeiouAEIOU')
```

Please do use a generator expression in `''.join()` and not a list comprehension; such a list comprehension would allocate memory unnecessarily.

Comment: Good answer but the last sentence is just not true. Always use a list comprehension when you use `str.join`. The argument for `join` will always be converted to a sequence so a generator expression is slower _and_ as memory efficient as a list comprehension.

Comment: @MSeifert Do you have a reference to back that claim up?

Comment: the reference is the python source code for `str.join`: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/unicodeobject.c#L9868, see also my other [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41083229/removing-characters-from-string-python/41083246?noredirect=1#comment69372767_41083255)

Comment: Yes, that "only" shows it's converted to a sequence. A generator is no sequence and converting a generator to a sequence is much slower than just creating a sequence in the first place.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `string.translate()` for this. For example:

```
def anti_vowel(text):
  return text.translate(None, "aeiouAEIOU")

print(anti_vowel("hello world"))
```

With Python 3 the `delete` argument is gone, but you can still do it by mapping a character to `None`.

```
def anti_vowel_py3(text):
   return text.translate({ord(i): None for i in "aeiouAEIOU"})

print(anti_vowel_py3("hello world"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code doesnt work because every iteration you assign `no_vowel` with the text all over again and you iterate the text's letters what you shouldnt because `replace` already does it. You should write it like that:

```
def anti_vowel(text):
    no_vowel = text
    for c in 'aeiouAEIOU':
        no_vowel = no_vowel.replace(c, '')

    return no_vowel
```

Or, you could use a list comprehension. More Pythonic and faster to run:

```
def anti_vowel(text):
    return ''.join([c for c in text if c not in 'aeiouAEIOU])
```

Comment: This doesn't work, it returns `"['H', 'l', 'l', ' ', 'W', 'r', 'l', 'd']"`. This does: `''.join(c for c in text if c not in 'aeiouAEIOU')`

Comment: You need to close off that string.

Comment: @leaf Because `str.join` needs a sequence (not a generator) so using a generator only adds needless overhead when it's converted to a list.

Comment: @MSeifert Perhaps your correct, but I'm still not really understating how using a generator is inefficient.

Comment: @leaf A generator is only useful if you don't need all elements or random access. You can check the source code (https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/unicodeobject.c#L9868) and documentation (https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/sequence.html#c.PySequence_Fast). In this case that's equivalent to `list(generator)` which is definetly slower than doing a list comprehension.

Comment: @MSeifert After looking over the source code at Github, it appears your correct. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 1):

In every iteration of the loop, text is "Hello World", and the last vowel of text is "o", so at the end of the loop, no_vowel is "Hell Wrld".

In python2.7, use method translate instead. Here is the official document:

> translate(...)
>
> ```
>  S.translate(table [,deletechars]) -> string
>
>  Return a copy of the string S, where all characters occurring
>  in the optional argument deletechars are removed, and the
>  remaining characters have been mapped through the given
>  translation table, which must be a string of length 256 or None.
>
>  If the table argument is None, no translation is applied and
>  the operation simply removes the characters in deletechars.
> ```

`"Hello World".translate(None, "aeiouAEIOU")` gives the correct result `"Hll Wrld"`

Also, `re.sub('[aeiouAEIOU]', "", "Hello World")` works for both python2.7 and python3

Comment: This doesn't work, and results in a `TypeError`: translate() takes exactly one argument (2 given).

Comment: @Sybren This works in Python2.7, but in python3, the parameter `deletechars` of method `translate` is gone.

Comment: @Sybren `re.sub('[aeiouAEIOU]', "", "Hello World")` will work for both python2.7 and python3